# Unable to receive SMS verification code for phone authentication in Firebase Auth

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm facing an issue with Firebase phone authentication. I've been trying to implement phone authentication using the `signInWithPhone` method from `@angular/fire/auth`. However, I'm not receiving the SMS verification code to my phone number. Here are the details of my implementation:

1. I'm using the `signInWithPhone` method to initiate the phone authentication flow.
2. I'm successfully getting the `ConfirmationResult` object after calling `signInWithPhone`, which contains the verificationId and other details.
3. However, the SMS with the verification code is not being received on my phone.

Here is a TypeScript snippet of the signInWithPhone$ method I am using:

```
public signInWithPhone$(phone: string): Observable<ConfirmationResult> {
  return from(signInWithPhoneNumber(this.auth, phone, new RecaptchaVerifier('recaptcha', { size: 'invisible' }, this.auth)));
}
```

I have already gone through the following troubleshooting steps:

1. Verified that my phone number is correctly provided in the code.
2. Ensured that the phone number format is valid for my country (Israel).
3. Confirmed that my Firebase project has the necessary configuration for phone authentication.
4. Checked that my phone number can receive SMS messages from other sources.

Despite these efforts, I'm still not receiving the verification code. I have also tried the suggested solutions from Stack Overflow and the Firebase documentation, but none of them have resolved the issue.

Has anyone in the community encountered a similar issue with Firebase phone authentication in Angular? Is there anything specific I need to configure or consider for phone authentication in Israel?